# Regex Capture Groups in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will split out a string in 3 different parts: Name, Address, and Phone Number.

This is what I currently have:

```
^(?<Name>\w.*)\s+(?<Address>\d+\s\w+.*\d{5,9})\s+(?<Phone>\d+.*)
```

Here is what [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7VnLPm/2) is giving me back with the following sample string:
[image]

But if I add in a '#' before the suite number, it works as planned:
[image]

I've even tried running just the address regex against the entire string in a separate instance and it worked just fine.  There's something going on with the capture groups that's throwing it off.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and expected outputs. Not all of our proxies allow us to get to Imgur.

Comment: Google the US Postal address reader/scanner for the thousands of different format's of addresses. Looks like it's a loosing battle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the name non-greedy:

```
^(?<Name>\w.*?)\s+(?<Address>\d+\s\w+.*\d{5,9})\s+(?<Phone>\d+.*)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!